# EventEditor into Extjs 4 Desktop example

Tags: extjs

How can I integrate [EventEditor](http://www.bryntum.com/examples/scheduler-latest/examples/eventeditor/editor.html) example as a module in [Extjs 4 desktop](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.1/examples/desktop/desktop.html) example ?.

Thanks for support